# Why isn't String() constructor private?

Tags: java

Is using a String() constructor as against string literal beneficial in any scenario?
Using string literals enable reuse of existing objects, so why do we need the public constructor? Is there any real world use?
For eg., both the literals point to the same object.

```
String name1 = "name";//new String("name") creates a new object.
String name2 = "name";
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One example where the constructor has a useful purpose: Strings created by `String.substring()` share the underlying `char[]` of the `String` they're created by. So if you have a `String` of length 10.000.000 (taking up 20MB of memory) and take its first 5 characters as substring then discard the original `String`, that substring will still keep the 20MB object from being eligible for garbage collection. Using the String constructor on it will avoid that, as it makes a copy of only the part of the underlying char array that's actually used by the `String` instance.

Of course, if you create and use a lot of substrings of the same `String`, especially if they overlap, then you'd very much want them to share the underlying `char[]`, and using the constructor would be counterproductive.

Comment: It was a beautiful lecture but it does not answer question from the header: "why isn't string constructor *private*?" String.subsring() may implement all its optimizations using private constructor as a method of class String. The question is why is this constructor public?!

Comment: @AlexR: Read the answer again, specifically the last sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: @jleedev: It has a completely different purpose (and should rarely be used).

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles on this question: note that this no longer applies since Java 7 update 6.

Answer (score 3):

Since string is immutable, operations like substring keep the original string that might be long. Using the constructor to create new string from the substring will create a new string and will allow dropping the old string (to GC). This way might free up needed memory.
Example:

```
String longS = "very long";
String shortS = new String(longS.substring(4));
```

Comment: @Erick: Nope, not necessarily identical. See Michael's answer.

Comment: @Erick: yes it will, because the underlying char array can be much larger than the "visible" String contents.

Comment: Michael explains this better.

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes you might want to create a copy and not just have a new reference to the same string.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a scenario?

Comment: I saw this morning a question about a WeakHashMap, which is a HashMap that removes an element automatically when its key is garbage collected. Turns out you shouldn't use string literals as keys with those because they would never get reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

All good answers here, but I think it's worth pointing out that the Java treats literals quite different than Strings constructed the traditional way.

This is [a good Q/A](http://www.codestyle.org/java/faq-Strings.shtml#stringconstructor) about it.